# Jenkins 2 ui layout stretches horizontally in job configuration page, text no longer wrapped

Tags: jenkins

Jenkins 2 has a UI problem in job configuration page. The UI layout stretches horizontally in Job Configuration page.

If there are long lines in any text area, the whole page is stretched to the width of the longest text line. This makes the Job Configuration page very hard to use.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem has been reported in

## Jenkins version 2.26, LTS 2.19.3 and above

This has been fixed.

Issue Report: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-27367

Github PR: https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/pull/2575

## Jenkins version below 2.26, LTS 2.19.3

For those who can not upgrade to the latest Jenkins version, here is another fix:

- Install [simple-theme-plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Simple+Theme+Plugin).
- Create a css file (`theme.css`) in `<jenkins_home>/userContent/`.
- Add following to the css file.

  ```
  td.setting-main .CodeMirror {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ```
- Point to your theme css (for example `http://<yourjenkins>/userContent/theme.css`) in jenkins system configuration page, section "Theme"